# Understanding EMR autoscaling

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-emr, boto

I have the following code, which is working fine:

```
def emr_client():
    config = get_aws_config()
    return boto3.client(
        'emr',
        region_name=config['aws_region'],
        aws_access_key_id=config['aws_access_key_id'],
        aws_secret_access_key=config['aws_secret_access_key']
    )


response = emr_client().run_job_flow(
        Name=cluster_name,
        ReleaseLabel="**********",
        Instances={
            'InstanceGroups': build_instance_groups_config(num_core_nodes, num_task_nodes, spots,
                                                           instance_type='r4.4xlarge'),
            'Ec2KeyName': '**********',
            'KeepJobFlowAliveWhenNoSteps': True,
            'TerminationProtected': False,
            'EmrManagedMasterSecurityGroup': '**********',
            'EmrManagedSlaveSecurityGroup': '**********',
            'Ec2SubnetId': '**********',
        },
        VisibleToAllUsers=True,
        JobFlowRole='EMR_EC2_DefaultRole',
        ServiceRole='EMR_DefaultRole',
        Applications=[
            {'Name': 'Hadoop'},
            {'Name': 'Spark'},
            {'Name': 'Ganglia'},
            {'Name': 'Zeppelin'}
        ],
        Tags=tags,
        Configurations=[
            {
                "Classification": "yarn-site",
                "Properties": {"yarn.nodemanager.vmem-check-enabled": "false"}
            }
        ]
    )
```

Now, I want to change it a little bit, in order to use auto scaling. Here is the relevant documentation: [RunJobFlow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/APIReference/API_RunJobFlow.html)

I see there something that's called  `"AutoScalingRole": "string"`, as well as  `"AutoScalingPolicy"` which is quite a large object, but I don't see any example showing how to populate it, and haven't found such on google either.

1. Could anybody provide me with an example?
2. Also, after I make the changes, how can I check that the autoscaling is really working?

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for custom auto scaling policy for EMR. You can find the detailed documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ManagementGuide/emr-automatic-scaling.html).

You first need to create IAM role or use `EMR_AutoScaling_DefaultRole` default rule for autoscaling. You need to put this into `AutoScalingRole`
You can create autoscaling `policy` and `rules` as described below in the documentation.

1. If you are creating a cluster, in the Amazon EMR console, select Create Cluster, select Go to advanced options, choose options for Step 1: Software and Steps, and then go to Step 2: Hardware Configuration. OR - If you are modifying an instance group in a running cluster, select your cluster from the cluster list, and then expand the Hardware section.
2. In Cluster scaling section, select Enable cluster saling. Then select Create a custom automatic scaling policy. In the table of Custom automatic scaling policies, click the pencil icon that appears in the row of the instance group you want to configure. The Auto Scaling rules screen opens.
3. Type the Maximum instances you want the instance group to contain after it scales out, and type the Minimum instances you want the instance group to contain after it scales in.
4. Click the pencil to edit rule parameters, click the X to remove a rule from the policy, and click Add rule to add additional rules.
5. Choose rule parameters as described earlier in this topic. For descriptions of available CloudWatch metrics for Amazon EMR, see Amazon EMR Metrics and Dimensions in the Amazon CloudWatch User Guide.

In the example below, we have some important metric that are defined in documentation as

> Maximum instances constraint specifies the maximum number of Amazon
> EC2 instances that can be in the instance group, and applies to all
> scale-out rules. Similarly, the Minimum instances constraint specifies
> the minimum number of Amazon EC2 instances and applies to all scale-in
> rules.

`Name` is the name of rule you created earlier.  `scaling_adjustment` is number of EC2 instances to add /terminate. `Cool down period` is the time threshold needed to be passed before applying next rule/actiivity.

```
"InstanceGroups": [ 
     { 
        "AutoScalingPolicy": { 
           "Constraints": { 
              "MaxCapacity": number,
              "MinCapacity": number
           },
           "Rules": [ 
              { 
                 "Action": { 
                    "Market": "string",
                    "SimpleScalingPolicyConfiguration": { 
                       "AdjustmentType": "string",
                       "CoolDown": number,
                       "ScalingAdjustment": number
                    }
                 },
                 "Description": "string",
                 "Name": "string",
                 "Trigger": { 
                    "CloudWatchAlarmDefinition": { 
                       "ComparisonOperator": "string",
                       "Dimensions": [ 
                          { 
                             "Key": "string",
                             "Value": "string"
                          }
                       ],
                       "EvaluationPeriods": number,
                       "MetricName": "string",
                       "Namespace": "string",
                       "Period": number,
                       "Statistic": "string",
                       "Threshold": number,
                       "Unit": "string"
                    }
                 }
              }
           ]
        },
        "BidPrice": "string",
        "Configurations": [ 
           { 
              "Classification": "string",
              "Configurations": [ 
                 "Configuration"
              ],
              "Properties": { 
                 "string" : "string" 
              }
           }
        ],
        "EbsConfiguration": { 
           "EbsBlockDeviceConfigs": [ 
              { 
                 "VolumeSpecification": { 
                    "Iops": number,
                    "SizeInGB": number,
                    "VolumeType": "string"
                 },
                 "VolumesPerInstance": number
              }
           ],
           "EbsOptimized": boolean
        },
        "InstanceCount": number,
        "InstanceRole": "string",
        "InstanceType": "string",
        "Market": "string",
        "Name": "string"
     }
  ],
```